# Write bytes, ints and byte buffers easily? C#

Tags: c#, arrays

My code looks like

```
mem.WriteByte(4);
mem.WriteByte(1);
mem.Write(HostPortBuf, 0, 2);
//more
```

Is it possible to write it like

```
mem.MyWrite(4, 1, HostPortBuf, //more);
```

Mem is currently a memorystream but i can easily build the array in one go so it doesn't need to be a stream. Is there anything like this? in C#?

Comment: You mean to make an extension method called `MyWrite`?

Comment: @lc. i dont care if its an extention, a function in some other namespace or a copy/pasteable standalone func that returns a byte buf. Its just an example of how i may write the entire contents in one go

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it's actually more readable, but here it is:

```
public static class MemoryStreamExtensions
{
    public static void Write(this MemoryStream stream, params object[] parameters)
    {
        if (stream != null)
        {
            foreach (var obj in parameters)
            {
                if (obj is byte)
                {
                    stream.WriteByte((byte)obj);
                }
                else if (obj is byte[])
                {
                    var theArray = (byte[])obj;
                    stream.Write(theArray, 0, theArray.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MemoryStream zz = new MemoryStream();
        zz.Write((byte)1, (byte)4, new byte[] { 5, 6 });

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to cast 1 and 4 as `byte`. If you don't, 1 and 4 type will be `int` (default type for those numbers), so it won't add two first bytes in your stream.

Comment: oh right hmm casting. I have an idea. This is exactly what i was thinking of doing but i was kind of lazy with writing code (i just wrote and debug 50lines of related code :x )

Comment: @acidzombie24 If you don't want to specifically cast values as byte, you could accept int instead. But in the extension method, you'll have to case the int into a byte. I didn't wrote it this way because it might be not trivial (i.e. what should the method do if the user tries to write 4587, which obviously doesn't fit in a single byte ?)

Answer (score 0):

I feel your current code is more readable.

But still, this maybe what you are looking for:

```
byte[] data = new byte[SIZE];
data[0] = 4;
data[1] = 1;
Array.Copy(HostPortBuf, 0, data, 2, HostPortBuf.Length);
mem.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```